block diagonalizing a 4x4 Hermitian matrix with vanishing anti diagonal elements
I need help diagonalizing the following 4x4 matrix that has a vanishing anti-diagonal:
\begin{align} H = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & 0 \\
b^* & d & 0 & e \\
c & 0 & f & g \\
0 & e & g^* & h
\end{pmatrix}\end{align}
The elements $a,b,c,e,f,h$ are all real, so the matrix H is Hermitian.
Is there any way or any unitary transformation that allows me to diagonalize this matrix blockwise? I.e. transform it into the form
\begin{align} \begin{pmatrix} A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}\end{align} so that $detH=detA\cdot detC$?

Is the Aitken block diagonalization of help? If the original matrix with partitioning into sub-matrices A, B, C, and D

then it can be decomposed as

or alternatively as


At first I thought it solves the problem, with:\begin{align}
\det(H-\lambda 1)= \det(URU_p - \lambda 1) = \det(URU_p - \lambda UU_p) = \det(U(R - \lambda 1)U_p)\end{align}
but unfortunately I cannot do this because $UU_p\neq1$

You can make use of 1) determinant of matrix product = product of determinants, and 2) determinant of triangular matrix = product of diagonal elements such that $\mathrm{det}(U) = \mathrm{det}(U_{p})=1$. So you are left with $\det(R - \lambda 1))$, i.e. looking for the eigenvalues of $R$, which is a block-diagonal matrix.

Sorry, I still don't think it works. Because $1\neq UU_p$ so you cannot do the step $\det(URU_p - \lambda 1)= \det(URU_p - \lambda UU_p)$. In fact I implemented this method numerically and didn't get the correct eigenvalues. But good try.
I think you you said is valid after the $\det(U(R-\lambda1)U_p)$ step. But this is not equal to $\det(H-\lambda 1)$

`a = rand + 1irand; b = rand + 1irand; c = rand + 1irand; d = rand + 1irand;
e= rand + 1irand; f = rand + 1irand; g = rand + 1irand; h = rand + 1irand;
H = [a,b,c,0;conj(b),d,0,e;c,0,f,g;0,e,conj(g),h];
A = [a,b;conj(b),d]; B = [c,0;0,e]; C = B; D = [f,g;conj(g),h];
% H = [A,B;C,D];
U = [eye(2,2),zeros(2,2);...
    C*inv(A),eye(2,2)];
Up = [eye(2,2),inv(A)*B;...
    zeros(2,2),eye(2,2)];
S = [A,zeros(2,2);...
    zeros(2,2),D-C*inv(A)*B];
disp(det(H))
disp(det(S)`


Maybe I get your question wrong, but if you decompose your matrix $H$ (which in the screenshot is called $R$) according to the product of a triangular matrix, a block diagonal matrix, and another triangular matrix, then the determinant of $H$ is equal to the determinant of the block diagonal matrix, even if $UU_p\neq1$. Or is your point that you are not interested in the determinant of $H$ but in the eigenvalues?

Yeah, my main goal is find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of H and I was hoping to use block diagonalization as a simplifying step, since it will allow me to solve two characteristic polynomials of degree 2 instead of one of degree 4. And finding the evs is much more manageable. I am not disputing that your decomposition is correct or that the product of the determents is what you mention. But for the eigenvalue problem it doesn't simplify the problem really since with your decomposition we need to solve:
$det(A-\lambda 1)det(D-\lambda 1 C(A-\lambda 1)^{-1}B)=0$ which is still of degree 4
